# several awk commands consecutively

Tags: awk

I'm using awk command to extract some datas. The point is that I need to use awk command several times to extract all informations I need and each time when I'm using awk I need create a temp file. My structure looks as below:

```
awk script1 output.txt > temp1.txt
awk script2 temp1.txt > temp2.txt
awk script3 temp2.txt > Final_output.txt
rm temp1.txt temp2.txt
```

Is there a way to eliminate the temp files? to execute several commands consecutively?

Comment: Is there any reason that you can not use pipes?  `|`

Comment: no reason. I'm new in Linux and I didn't know that's possible;-) Pipes are working, you helped me a lot, thank You!

Comment: You might even go further and combine the awk scripts in a single one.

Comment: You might even go further and accept the answer that's been posted in the meantime. Best thing would have been to invite @Hennes to produce an answer out of his comment so you could accept it. This way, everyone will know that your question has been answered satisfactorily.

Answer (score 1):

Your example can be executed using:

```
awk script1 output.txt | awk script2 | awk script3 > Final_output.txt
```

If you can combine the scripts (depends on what you will actually do), the line gets even shorter:

```
awk script123 output.txt > Final_output.txt
```